# Events in rails (such reminders, stopwatch, etc)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, events, asynchronous

my app has a timer (like an egg boiling timer)

The user enters a time to countdown to, and I'd like some action in a controller to occur once the timer is zero.

as requested - I'd like to have the capability of a user following several timers or timed events such as calendar. Since each user can time their events as they wish, the reminder/time's up functionality needs to give a notice to the user (by pop up message, email, etc)

using DelayedJob and whenever won't help here since they are all predefined times to events
One option to use those gems is to poll an action that will test all timers every second for all users but that doesn't scale very well or efficient..

How would I call an action exactly when the timer is up?

Comment: Please give more background on this topic. Why do you need this?

Comment: I need it for example if I have many users, and each inputs his birthday, I'd like that on that date the user will get an email. so now same example, but instead of a specific date, its more accurate to the minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found what I was looking for - the clockwork gem

https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork